# C file ruined - possible to fix?

Tags: c, file

I have a C-file that I ran yesterday, and it worked perfectly. Now, when I try to open it, it's a mess (only 1's and 0's and some random letters in between). I can't understand what have happened, but it's a bit of a crisis as I need to deliver this for a school project in about 2 hours. Anyone that can know what the problem is?

Comment: I bet when you compiled it, you put the compiled file on top of the source code file.

Comment: Did you open the wrong file? Overwrite the source with the binary? Encoding issue?

Comment: What compiler command did you use? If it was something like `g++ my_file.cpp -o my_file.cpp && ./my_file.cpp` you are done :P

Comment: Hmm..  I didn't realize that was possible.  I guess the linker does not try to open the executable output file until after the compiler has closed all the source and object files.

Comment: Can you do a Blackadder-style rewrite?   The code worked, so you already know how to structure it and what bugs you had.

Comment: Also, did your editor make an auto-backup?  If so, DON'T SAVE AND EXIT NOW, JUST QUIT!

Comment: I hope that you accidentally opened the executable and not the source file - if that's the case, your source is still there and you just have the wrong file open.

Comment: @MartinJames Yes, but don't you just spend all night trying to define *aardvark* only to have the original author burn it?

Comment: @MartinJames Yes, it is possible to overwrite one of the source files with the output. I consider this to be a MAJOR bug in the compiler driver, since I can think of no *sensible* use-case where the user would actually want that to happen.  While we're on the subject, I also think it's absurd that (in the year 2014) the default output filename is still `a.out`.  If the compiler used a sensible default output filename, then typically the `-o` option wouldn't be needed (reducing the chances of overwriting the input).

Comment: @user3386109 yeah - if not specified, it could append some date/time string to the name of the first obj file it linked, something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comments, the most likely cause of this problem was that you overwrote the source file with the executable file, probably by compiling with something like

```
gcc myfile.c -o myfile.c
```

After I did this once, I wrote the following simple script to avoid ever doing it again.  The script takes a single filename as input, strips the extension to create the output filename, **verifies that the output filename is actually different than the input filename**, and then invokes the compiler.

```
if [[ $1 == "" ]] 
then echo Usage: scc filename.c; echo; exit 
fi

if [[ $2 != "" ]]
then echo Sorry, only one parameter is allowed; echo; exit
fi

fullfilename=${1}
basefilename=${1%.c}

if [[ $basefilename == $fullfilename ]]
then echo "Error: invalid filename"; echo; exit
fi

echo gcc -Wall $1 -o $basefilename
gcc -Wall $1 -o $basefilename
```

On my system, the script file path is "~/utils/sensibleCC" and I have the following line in my shell startup file

```
alias "scc=~/utils/sensibleCC"
```

That way, if I type the following command

```
scc hello.c
```

the compiler is invoked with

```
gcc -Wall hello.c -o hello
```

Comment: Or, use `make`'s implicit rules: `make hello`.

Comment: @juanchopanza Ok, but how would you get the `-Wall` into the command line.

Comment: By setting `CFLAGS= -Wall -Wextra -other_flags_you _may_need` in a `Makefile` in the same directory you call `make` from.

Comment: @juanchopanza Ok, thanks. You should post that as the answer, and you'll get my upvote :)

Comment: Or `export CFLAGS="-Wall -Wextra"` to set the flags, avoiding the need for a makefile.

Comment: I prefer to have everything explicitly set in the makefile, and not depend on the environment if possible. But that's just me.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks again :)

Comment: I'm betting this is exactly what I did. It really sucks, as I didn't get to deliver my assignment and therefore can't finish the course. But, to stay positive, I won't ever do the same mistake again ;-)

Comment: @user16655 that's actually a good thing, in a way...

Comment: @user16655 I'm really sorry to hear that you won't be able to finish the course.  It's the worst feeling in the world when hours of work vaporize in an instant.  But that's the (computerized) world that we live in.  All the best in the future!